# How to convert SVG String to PNG?

Tags: php, javascript, svg, jquery-svg

I know that there are various topics about this but i haven't found the right answer...

I need to transform a SVG string to a png image, it has to be a png image because i need the transparency and for what i'm trying to use it only accepts png (or gift) images...

I need to do this through **php** or **javascript**...

I've been reading about Raphael but it only returns the image in a  way, and i need the image file !!!!

Also i've been trying with image magick (php ext) and it give me this error:

> **no decode delegate for this image format**

I hope anybody can help !!!

Thanks!

This is my SVG File...

```
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="560" height="300">
<defs>
<clipPath id="highcharts-6">
<rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="none" x="0" y="0" width="9999" height="300" stroke-width="0.000001">
</rect>
</clipPath>
<clipPath id="highcharts-7">
<rect fill="none" x="0" y="0" width="560" height="300">
</rect>
</clipPath>
</defs>
<g class="highcharts-series-group" >
</g>
<g class="highcharts-shadow" >
<path fill="none" d="M 279.96944901944573 0.0000031112080876027903 A 150 150 0 0 1 326.3009125168081 292.6752448748937 L 280 150 A 0 0 0 0 0 280 150 Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" stroke-linejoin="round"  stroke-opacity="0.049999999999999996" transform="translate(1, 1)">
</path>
<path fill="none" d="M 279.96944901944573 0.0000031112080876027903 A 150 150 0 0 1 326.3009125168081 292.6752448748937 L 280 150 A 0 0 0 0 0 280 150 Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" stroke-linejoin="round"  stroke-opacity="0.09999999999999999" transform="translate(1, 1)">
</path>
<path fill="none" d="M 279.96944901944573 0.0000031112080876027903 A 150 150 0 0 1 326.3009125168081 292.6752448748937 L 280 150 A 0 0 0 0 0 280 150 Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" stroke-linejoin="round"  stroke-opacity="0.15" transform="translate(1, 1)">
</path>
</g>
<g class="highcharts-shadow" >
<path fill="none" d="M 326.3007698415401 292.67529117573486 A 150 150 0 0 1 133.00773034195186 179.88766736926223 L 280 150 A 0 0 0 0 0 280 150 Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" stroke-linejoin="round"  stroke-opacity="0.049999999999999996" transform="translate(1, 1)">
</path>
<path fill="none" d="M 326.3007698415401 292.67529117573486 A 150 150 0 0 1 133.00773034195186 179.88766736926223 L 280 150 A 0 0 0 0 0 280 150 Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" stroke-linejoin="round"  stroke-opacity="0.09999999999999999" transform="translate(1, 1)">
</path>
<path fill="none" d="M 326.3007698415401 292.67529117573486 A 150 150 0 0 1 133.00773034195186 179.88766736926223 L 280 150 A 0 0 0 0 0 280 150 Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" stroke-linejoin="round"  stroke-opacity="0.15" transform="translate(1, 1)">
</path>
</g>
<g class="highcharts-shadow" >
<path fill="none" d="M 133.007700454358 179.88752037697762 A 150 150 0 0 1 156.4888806240783 64.88241432872512 L 280 150 A 0 0 0 0 0 280 150 Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" stroke-linejoin="round"  stroke-opacity="0.049999999999999996" transform="translate(1, 1)">
</path>
<path fill="none" d="M 133.007700454358 179.88752037697762 A 150 150 0 0 1 156.4888806240783 64.88241432872512 L 280 150 A 0 0 0 0 0 280 150 Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" stroke-linejoin="round"  stroke-opacity="0.09999999999999999" transform="translate(1, 1)">
</path>
<path fill="none" d="M 133.007700454358 179.88752037697762 A 150 150 0 0 1 156.4888806240783 64.88241432872512 L 280 150 A 0 0 0 0 0 280 150 Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" stroke-linejoin="round"  stroke-opacity="0.15" transform="translate(1, 1)">
</path>
</g>
<g class="highcharts-shadow" >
<path fill="none" d="M 156.48896574172574 64.8822908176483 A 150 150 0 0 1 217.00753341120077 13.867898153818942 L 280 150 A 0 0 0 0 0 280 150 Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" stroke-linejoin="round"  stroke-opacity="0.049999999999999996" transform="translate(1, 1)">
</path>
<path fill="none" d="M 156.48896574172574 64.8822908176483 A 150 150 0 0 1 217.00753341120077 13.867898153818942 L 280 150 A 0 0 0 0 0 280 150 Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" stroke-linejoin="round"  stroke-opacity="0.09999999999999999" transform="translate(1, 1)">
</path>
<path fill="none" d="M 156.48896574172574 64.8822908176483 A 150 150 0 0 1 217.00753341120077 13.867898153818942 L 280 150 A 0 0 0 0 0 280 150 Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" stroke-linejoin="round"  stroke-opacity="0.15" transform="translate(1, 1)">
</path>
</g>
<g class="highcharts-shadow" >
<path fill="none" d="M 217.00766954333415 13.867835161420402 A 150 150 0 0 1 273.3436894553766 0.14776101127640118 L 280 150 A 0 0 0 0 0 280 150 Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" stroke-linejoin="round"  stroke-opacity="0.049999999999999996" transform="translate(1, 1)">
</path>
<path fill="none" d="M 217.00766954333415 13.867835161420402 A 150 150 0 0 1 273.3436894553766 0.14776101127640118 L 280 150 A 0 0 0 0 0 280 150 Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" stroke-linejoin="round"  stroke-opacity="0.09999999999999999" transform="translate(1, 1)">
</path>
<path fill="none" d="M 217.00766954333415 13.867835161420402 A 150 150 0 0 1 273.3436894553766 0.14776101127640118 L 280 150 A 0 0 0 0 0 280 150 Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" stroke-linejoin="round"  stroke-opacity="0.15" transform="translate(1, 1)">
</path>
</g>
<g class="highcharts-shadow" >
<path fill="none" d="M 273.3438393076189 0.1477543550407745 A 150 150 0 0 1 279.9415029437792 0.00001140635239949006 L 280 150 A 0 0 0 0 0 280 150 Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" stroke-linejoin="round"  stroke-opacity="0.049999999999999996" transform="translate(1, 1)">
</path>
<path fill="none" d="M 273.3438393076189 0.1477543550407745 A 150 150 0 0 1 279.9415029437792 0.00001140635239949006 L 280 150 A 0 0 0 0 0 280 150 Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" stroke-linejoin="round"  stroke-opacity="0.09999999999999999" transform="translate(1, 1)">
</path>
<path fill="none" d="M 273.3438393076189 0.1477543550407745 A 150 150 0 0 1 279.9415029437792 0.00001140635239949006 L 280 150 A 0 0 0 0 0 280 150 Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" stroke-linejoin="round"  stroke-opacity="0.15" transform="translate(1, 1)">
</path>
</g>
<g class="highcharts-point" >
<path fill="#4572A7" d="M 279.96944901944573 0.0000031112080876027903 A 150 150 0 0 1 326.3009125168081 292.6752448748937 L 280 150 A 0 0 0 0 0 280 150 Z" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" stroke-linejoin="round">
</path>
<path fill="rgb(192,192,192)" d="M 279.96944901944573 0.0000031112080876027903 A 150 150 0 0 1 326.3009125168081 292.6752448748937 L 280 150 A 0 0 0 0 0 280 150 Z"  fill-opacity="0.000001" visibility="visible" style="">
</path>
</g>
<g class="highcharts-point" >
<path fill="#AA4643" d="M 326.3007698415401 292.67529117573486 A 150 150 0 0 1 133.00773034195186 179.88766736926223 L 280 150 A 0 0 0 0 0 280 150 Z" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" stroke-linejoin="round">
</path>
<path fill="rgb(192,192,192)" d="M 326.3007698415401 292.67529117573486 A 150 150 0 0 1 133.00773034195186 179.88766736926223 L 280 150 A 0 0 0 0 0 280 150 Z"  fill-opacity="0.000001" visibility="visible" style="">
</path>
</g>
<g class="highcharts-point" >
<path fill="#89A54E" d="M 133.007700454358 179.88752037697762 A 150 150 0 0 1 156.4888806240783 64.88241432872512 L 280 150 A 0 0 0 0 0 280 150 Z" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" stroke-linejoin="round">
</path>
<path fill="rgb(192,192,192)" d="M 133.007700454358 179.88752037697762 A 150 150 0 0 1 156.4888806240783 64.88241432872512 L 280 150 A 0 0 0 0 0 280 150 Z"  fill-opacity="0.000001" visibility="visible" style="">
</path>
</g>
<g class="highcharts-point" >
<path fill="#80699B" d="M 156.48896574172574 64.8822908176483 A 150 150 0 0 1 217.00753341120077 13.867898153818942 L 280 150 A 0 0 0 0 0 280 150 Z" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" stroke-linejoin="round">
</path>
<path fill="rgb(192,192,192)" d="M 156.48896574172574 64.8822908176483 A 150 150 0 0 1 217.00753341120077 13.867898153818942 L 280 150 A 0 0 0 0 0 280 150 Z"  fill-opacity="0.000001" visibility="visible" style="">
</path>
</g>
<g class="highcharts-point" >
<path fill="#3D96AE" d="M 217.00766954333415 13.867835161420402 A 150 150 0 0 1 273.3436894553766 0.14776101127640118 L 280 150 A 0 0 0 0 0 280 150 Z" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" stroke-linejoin="round">
</path>
<path fill="rgb(192,192,192)" d="M 217.00766954333415 13.867835161420402 A 150 150 0 0 1 273.3436894553766 0.14776101127640118 L 280 150 A 0 0 0 0 0 280 150 Z"  fill-opacity="0.000001" visibility="visible" style="">
</path>
</g>
<g class="highcharts-point" >
<path fill="#DB843D" d="M 273.3438393076189 0.1477543550407745 A 150 150 0 0 1 279.9415029437792 0.00001140635239949006 L 280 150 A 0 0 0 0 0 280 150 Z" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" stroke-linejoin="round">
</path>
<path fill="rgb(192,192,192)" d="M 273.3438393076189 0.1477543550407745 A 150 150 0 0 1 279.9415029437792 0.00001140635239949006 L 280 150 A 0 0 0 0 0 280 150 Z"  fill-opacity="0.000001" visibility="visible" style="">
</path>
</g>
<g class="highcharts-legend" >
<rect rx="5" ry="5" fill="none" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="7" height="7" stroke-width="1" stroke="#909090" visibility="hidden">
</rect>
<g  clip-path="url(#highcharts-6)">
<g>
</g>
</g>
</g>
<g class="highcharts-tooltip"  style="padding:0;white-space:nowrap;" visibility="hidden">
<rect rx="5" ry="5" fill="none" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" stroke-width="5" fill-opacity="0.85"  stroke="black" stroke-opacity="0.049999999999999996" transform="translate(1, 1)">
</rect>
<rect rx="5" ry="5" fill="none" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" stroke-width="3" fill-opacity="0.85"  stroke="black" stroke-opacity="0.09999999999999999" transform="translate(1, 1)">
</rect>
<rect rx="5" ry="5" fill="none" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="0.85"  stroke="black" stroke-opacity="0.15" transform="translate(1, 1)">
</rect>
<rect rx="5" ry="5" fill="rgb(255,255,255)" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" stroke-width="2" fill-opacity="0.85">
</rect>
<text x="5" y="18" style="font-family:'lucida grande', 'lucida sans unicode', verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#333333;fill:#333333;" >
</text>
</g>
<g class="highcharts-tracker" >
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

can you share your svg file text structure ? I was too having same error and then i figured out problem is with structure of text in svg file itself . now my svg file looks like below, which works as expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">path tags</svg>
```

Comment: I had a similar problem... PHP's Imagick was churning out errors when trying to `readImageBlob` -- simply prepending the XML declaration fixed the errors. However, I just get a blank (white) image? Any ideas?

Comment: can you share your path tags? something might be wrong with that, that's why its not being drawn and you are getting blank image.

Comment: The SVG files are extracted from a database and are quite long, but I've created a [static file here](http://railmanager.co.uk/assets/img/004.svg). It may be something to do with a lack of height/width, but the command-line `convert.exe` works like a charm.

Comment: yes, if you have not set width height, that might be a problem. try like this: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><svg width="720" height="445" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">path tags</svg>

Comment: and in php, i have done  $im->readImageBlob($svg);
            $im->setImageFormat("png24");
            $im->resizeImage(720, 445, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);$im->writeImage("myImage.png");